# Custom Time Periods with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, date-arithmetic

I've got the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

offset = 3 * pd.tseries.offsets.BMonthEnd()

bond_index_1 = pd.date_range('1/1/14', '1/1/18', freq=offset, name='date')
bond_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.uniform(0, 5, 16),
                      index= bond_index_1, columns=['cash_flow'])

bond_index_2 = pd.date_range('3/1/14', '3/1/21', freq=offset, name='date')
bond_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = 2*np.random.uniform(0, 10, 28),
                      index= bond_index_2, columns=['cash_flow'])

df_merged = pd.concat([bond_1, bond_2], keys=['Bond_1', 'Bond_2'])
```

How can I get a sum of the values in the `cash_flow` column by a **custom range, starting at 2014-6-30, ending at 2016-12-31 in 6 Month intervals**.

Therefore, the intervals would look like 2014-06-30, 2015-12-31, 2015-06-30, 2015-12-31, 2016-06-30, 2016-12-31

It would also ignore the 'bond' name index in the MultiIndex.

I've tried using `TimeGrouper` but couldn't get it to work since `TimeGrouper` starts at the earliest value in your time series and moves forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) seems one of the easy way to solve your problem.

```
print df_merged.reset_index().set_index('date').resample('6M', how='sum', closed='left', loffset='-1M')
```

yield,

```
            cash_flow
date                 
2014-06-30  16.058478
2014-12-31  24.282106
2015-06-30  32.777176
2015-12-31  33.661801
2016-06-30  26.779571
2016-12-31  17.435089
2017-06-30  30.914194
2017-12-31  20.117823
2018-06-30  29.505178
2018-12-31  17.245787
2019-06-30  22.975058
2019-12-31  17.742220
2020-06-30  11.646266
2020-12-31  20.077632
```

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for the response.  I missed the fact that you can apply an offset to the resample.